# Running inline SELECT statements with EF CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I’m new with .Net Core and I’m working on porting over a .Net Framework console app to Core 3.1.5 console app.

With EF in .Net Framework I could use `ctx.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` to run some complex SQL statements that would be real tricky to run a LINQ statement in EF. Using inline SQL would also let me write out the SQL statement for debugging in a much nicer looking statement compared to logging EF’s SQL statement which can be very difficult to read with multiple JOINS.

Looking into this with Core it seems as though in EF Core you can use `Database.ExecuteSqlCommand` but only for Insert/Update/Delete and not Select. To run inline SQL as a Select statement in EF Core it looks as though you have to use an entity model to select against `ex: ctx.Entity.FromSql(“myquery”)`. Thing is the queries we use can have JOINS to multiple tables or even FUNCTIONS.

Can you run inline Select SQL statements that have JOINS or Functions against a single entity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the return from your query must be records of the type of the Entity.  The Entity does not need to be mapped to a specific object in the database, but can be a [Keyless Entity Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types?tabs=data-annotations).

Comment: Thanks @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: I'll look at the Keyless Entity. Hope I can get something to work because every time I think I have enough code examples for my team to start using Core over Framework some road block comes up to keep us from using Core.